# Cannot add “rowversion” data type in sql server 2008 r2 management studio, or even to modify existing column data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a column with `Rowversion` data type, but inside my SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio, I cannot find such a data type:

[image]

Also when I tried altering existing column named `timestamp` which is of type `timestamp` using this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [SkillManagement].[dbo].[Customer]
ALTER COLUMN timestamp rowversion
```

I get this error:

> Msg 4927, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot alter column 'timestamp' to be data type timestamp

Can anyone advise?